# Ionic2 ngOnInit, ionViewWillEnter, and nav-push

Tags: ionic2

I have this case where navigating by a `[nav-push]` from a `ion-item` to a details page, on the details page `ionViewWillEnter` is not invoked, while the `ngOnInit` does.

```
//ion-item on list page...
<button ion-item detail-push
          *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"
          [navPush]="recipeEditPage"
          [navParams]="{recipe:recipe}">
        <h2>{{recipe.title}}</h2>
</button>

//details page, ionWillEnter doesn't fire, white ngOnInit does.
  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.navParams.data.recipe){
      this._mode = RecipeEditPage.Modes.EDIT;
      this._recipe=this.navParams.data.recipe;
    }
    else
      this._recipe = this.recipeSrv.getNewRecipe();
  }
```

Thanks! F.

Comment: how is your code with ionViewWillEnter?

Comment: 100% as the one you can see with ngOnInit, I just replace that method with ionViewWillEnter, and I don't implement the interface in the page class.